# Loading local javascript file from one directory level above

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest

I am currently contracted to a place that cannot use a CMS or PHP, but they want me to build something like a CMS using HTML and JavaScript.

I know it sounds ridiculous but I do not want to be searching for another job these days and they are the nicest people that I have ever worked for - EVER - and I old.

One of the concepts of a CMS is to have global files that you can include at any given time.

As a result, I tried the $.ajax, $.get, etc..., but I was running into issues of Access URI denied and those kind of things for trying to load a file which is one directory level the current directory.

I was able to get the javascript file to load by using the old XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject.

However, the script within the div that has been loaded cannot be called. I receive an error of "Can't find variable: mFunc" which is the name of the function that has been loaded into the div.

Here's the code for my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>retrieve local file one level up</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var createRequestObject = function(){   
    var req;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // Firefox, Safari, Opera...
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        // Internet Explorer 5+
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        alert('There was a problem creating the XMLHttpRequest object');
    }   
    return req; 
}

    // Make the XMLHttpRequest object
    var http = createRequestObject();


var sendRequestPost = function(){
    var jscript = '../test.js';
    // Open PHP script for requests
    http.open('GET', jscript);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponsePost;
    http.send(null);
    var mT = setTimeout("mFunc()", 2000);
}

var handleResponsePost = function(){
    if(http.readyState == 1){
        document.getElementById('mDiv').innerHTML = "Please wait, loading... " ; 
    }else if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        // Text returned from PHP script
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('mDiv').innerHTML = response;

        if(response){
            // Update ajaxTest2 content
            document.getElementById('mDiv').innerHTML = response;
        }
    }else if(http.readyState == 2){
        document.getElementById('mDiv').innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }else if(http.readyState == 3){
        document.getElementById('mDiv').innerHTML = http.responseText;
    }
}
-->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="javascript:sendRequestPost();">
<div id="mDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript that loads just fine into mDiv:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var mFunc = function(){
    var mScript = document.createElement("script");
    mScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    var data = 'alert("gets here");'
    mScript.text = data;

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(mScript);
}
-->
</script>
```

Yet, after the two seconds have passed, I receive the error.

I am sure that it is probably because the browser just sees this as text within the div, so how do I make it recognize that it is javascript.

I have tried using eval, which I do not want to use, but even returns a parse error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW, if I use document.writeln(http.responseText) instead of document.getElementById('mDiv').innerHTML = http.responseText, then it will overwrite everything in the body and the script will execute, but there is nothing else in the document but the new script in the head section. Another BTW, why is it only loading on http.readyState == 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, another programmer that I work with, has found a simple solution.

Instead trying to use ajax to load a JavaScript file from a higher directory level and then run a document.writeln or document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML -- reverse the steps.

Include the JS file as you would normally:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../common/header.js"></script>
```

Within this JS file

```
function CommonHeader(mPath) {
    document.writeln('<header>');
    document.writeln('  <div class="PageWidth">');
    document.writeln('      <h1><a href="' + mPath + 'index.html"     title="Something">Something<sup>&reg;</sup></a> <a  href="http://www.xyz.com/abc.html" title="Learn more about us."><em>Learn about us</em></a></h1>');
    document.writeln('      <nav>');
    document.writeln('          <ul>');
    document.writeln('              <li id="loginOut"></li>');
```

The order needs to be for you to call document.writeln at the beginning of the process.

We can now load header.js, footer.js, and whatever other file that we wish to load, along with having an array at the top of each page denoting the path to those files, for lower directory level htmls

```
dynamicPathArr[0] = "../../";
```

Then within whatever file, you can call the function to write the date into the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">CommonHeader(dynamicPathArr[0])</script>
```

I cannot believe that I did not think of this completely simple solution.

Although this is not SEO friendly, it is good for only updating header, footer, nav, etc... in one location, until everything is finalized.

And thanks you for the response

Answer (score 1):

`../` has meaning to the local filesystem (on most platforms), but not to HTML or to most webservers. Remember that the URL is just a query string for the server.

Generally speaking, you need to parse the URL to remove the undesired few elements. If you just want scripts that are common across the website, though, they should be referenced from the root, so the relative URL would begin with `/`.

A quick hack would be `/(.*)\/.*/.exec( '/foo/bar/baz.html' )[1]`. This doesn't handle the query string following `?` or anchor following `#` but you won't have a query on a static website, and won't have anchors until you get into more advanced techniques. jQuery has a better utility for parsing URLs, also based on regexps.

It's offtopic for this site, but you will have to be *very* familiar with XHR to implement a JavaScript CMS.